# Automatically Jump to Current Time and Highlight Row in a Excel Sheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a schedule maker in Excel that tracks the activities I should do throughout the day. The Excel sheet looks something like this:

[image]

The sheet looks good, in my opinion. The only problem is that it has 97 rows, which makes finding the current task somewhat difficult -- having to scroll the sheet up and down until locating the current time (thereby defeating the purpose of having it in the first place).

I was wondering whether it is possible to program Excel to automatically highlight or move the sheet to the row representing the current time? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a conditional formatting, based on this formula:

```
=AND(DAY(A1)=DAY(NOW());
     MONTH(A1)=MONTH(NOW());
     YEAR(A1)=YEAR(NOW()))
```